# Changing part of the html page without refreshing whole page

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a html page and a java application with Thymeleaf templating engine and I'm looking for a tutorial to make a request to the server and render only part of the page based on response.

At this moment, I have some buttons having a link of the same page with a different parameter, my  div is created based on attribute articleList (which I receive from the server based on button_id)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/index?button_id=1"> button 1 </a>
<a href="/index?button_id=2"> button 2 </a>

<div class="" th:each="article : ${articleList}">
    <p th:text="${article.getText()}">Article</p>
```

**Java:**

```
public class NodController implements IGTVGController {
  public void process(
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final ServletContext servletContext, final TemplateEngine templateEngine) 
        throws Exception {

    final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, request.getLocale());

    Integer button_id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("button_id"));
    List<String> articleList = getArticleList(button_id);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("articleList",articleList);

    templateEngine.process("/index", ctx, response.getWriter());
    }
```

I want my buttons to process my index controller and only change the div with the articles and not refresh the entire page.

I have tried using ajax but I didn't find code examples for server-side that I could understand, so I don't know how to process the request and I don't know how to use servlets. Also I didn't manage to send any request to my current controller.

I have also found in thymeleaf api this method:

```
public final void process(String templateName, IContext context,
                      IFragmentSpec fragmentSpec, Writer writer)
```

where IFragmentSpec should "select a fragment of a template to be processed (once read and parsed), discarding the rest of the template" but I couldn't find more information about it as how to use it or if it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look into jQuery's AJAX functions, specifically the load() function. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I've been trying to understand and use Ajax, but all I could learn is how to load data from a .txt, .xml or .html file. But for my specific example, I still have no clue how to get data from the server

Comment: You would setup a separate file that retrieves the data from the server and then load that file using AJAX. This may help - http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Try putting that section into an UpdatePanel

Comment: In case you want other than AJAX, take a look at JSF (Java Server Faces 2.0) which internally uses ajax in some components. That way you don't need to use ajax and still can get your work done.

Comment: The way I used to do that is keep the part of page that is to be changed in a frame and reload the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the javascript code

```
//get text 1 by ajax
    function getText1(urlstarted) {
        xmlHttp = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (xmlHttp.overrideMimeType) {
                // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
                //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('text/html');
            }
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
        if (!xmlHttp) {
            alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }

        var url=urlstarted+"/jsp/viewText1.jsp"; //put the link to ur Ajax page here
         xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = startAjaxingText;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function startAjaxingText() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) {

            document.getElementById('image').style.display='block' ;
            document.getElementById('result').style.display='none' ;
        }

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {




                    document.getElementById('image').style.display='none' ;
                    document.getElementById('result').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;


            } else {
                alert("There was a problem with the request.");
            }
        }

    }
//get text 2 by ajax
    function getText2(urlstarted) {
        xmlHttp = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (xmlHttp.overrideMimeType) {
                // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
                //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('text/html');
            }
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
        if (!xmlHttp) {
            alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }

        var url=urlstarted+"/jsp/viewText2.jsp"; //put the link to ur Ajax page here
         xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = startAjaxingText2;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function startAjaxingText2() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) {

            document.getElementById('image').style.display='block' ;
            document.getElementById('result').style.display='none' ;
        }

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {




                    document.getElementById('image').style.display='none' ;
                    document.getElementById('result').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;


            } else {
                alert("There was a problem with the request.");
            }
        }

    }
```

---

now your buttons will look like this

```
    <input name="button_1" id="button_1" type="button" value="button_1" onclick="getText1('<%=request.getContextPath()%>');" />
     <input name="button_2" id="button_2" type="button" value="button_2" 
onclick="getText2('<%=request.getContextPath()%>');" />
```

your div will look like

```
<div id="image" style="display:none"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading...."/> </div>
                <div id="result" style="display:none"></div></td>
```

your viewText1.jsp page that doing ajax part

```
out.println("text1");//or any logic u want
```

your viewText2.jsp page that doing ajax part

```
 out.println("text2");//or any logic u want
```

**note that :** the result of viewText1.jsp or viewText2.jsp  must be a text either a table  or paragraphs

Comment: also you can make the two javascript functions in one and send the page url by parameter via the button that calls it

Comment: Thank you, this needed a few twitches but it was a good example which I understood and helped me do my job.

Answer (score 1):

## Client-side implementation

You will have to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to load content from the server dynamically.

1. Consider designing your frontend as [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Look into [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).
2. Also, you can use old-school approach by using something like [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) if this is just a small area of your application.

## Separation of concerns

I strongly suggest to consider the idea to separate concerns by using server as a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service and frontend as a client. This is the best practice for large applications if you want to keep them maintainable and scalable.

You should look for tutorials of how to implement REST with your server-side technology. It's very common practice so I think you should be able to find one.

If you have any questions I will be glad to update this answer.